# MySQL error when targetrule indexer is executed

Tags: magento-enterprise, error, mysql, indexer, targetrule

I'm trying to run the targetrule indexer in my terminal and it shows some syntax error

#### Command:

```
php indexer.php --reindex targetrule
```

#### Error:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`giftease`.`enterprise_targetrule_index_crosssell_product`, CONSTRAINT `FK_94AAB744E142C77E39E72506AB13F090` FOREIGN KEY (`targetrule_id`) REFERENCES `giftease`.`enterprise_targetrule_index_cr)' in /var/www/html/giftease-upgrade/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:243
```

#### I've tried this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE enterprise_targetrule_index_crosssell_product;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

With no success

Answer (score 2):

It's better to

1. Remove existing constraints
2. Perform TRUNCATE operation(s)
3. Manually delete rows that now have references to "nowhere", i.e. non-existent relations
4. Re-create constraints

rather than disabling foreign key checks as you might run into data integrity issues.

Comment: the table already empty only

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you are trying to say. Did it work for you?